# Python PANDAS how to drop all rows in dataframe, with duplicate column value, if specific cell in a row is a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a little different and I can't find it anywhere.  Even good ol' ChatGPT is stuck, so asking real humans.

I have a dataframe like so:

| oldVoucherId | valuePurchased | valueRemaining |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 |  |
| 1 |  | 50 |
| 1 |  | 40 |
| 2 | 70 |  |
| 2 |  | 60 |
| 2 |  | 0 |
| 5 | 50 |  |
| 5 |  | 45 |
| 5 |  | 0 |
| 3 | 40 |  |
| 3 |  | 0 |
| 8 | 50 |  |
| 9 | 70 |  |

I want pandas to remove any rows, that share a voucher ID, that have a 0 valueRemaining.

So it would look like this when done:

| oldVoucherId | valuePurchased | valueRemaining |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 40 |
| 8 |  | 50 |
| 9 |  | 70 |

In this case, voucher 1 still has $40 remaining and vouchers 8 and 9 have never been used, so they need to stay also.

How can I somehow get PANDAS to remove those rows that share the same voucher ID, if the condition of valueRemainging is set to 0?

Thank you so much...

UPDATE:  This sample data should work:

```
data = {'oldVoucherId': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '5', '5', '5', '3', '3', '8', '9'],
                    'valuePurchased': ['60','','','70','','','50','','','40','','50','70'],
                    'valueRemaining': ['','50','40','','60','0','','45','0','','0','','']}

            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Your sample data doesn't convert to a dataframe because the lists are different lengths. 

You need to create a minimal example that reproduces your error. Then fire up a fresh python session and run the example to confirm that every fails as expected. Cutting corners in asking your question wastes your time and, more importantly, the time of those that might help you

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide the data frame in way that I can easily create it and mess around with it. So this is just a guess.

I would do a groupby + filter operation

```py
result = (
  df.groupby("oldVoucherId")
    .filter(lambda g: g["valueRemaining"].eq(0).any())
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but no luck.  I have also added sample data which should work.  Thank you for your suggestion.  I'll keep hunting

Comment: @robster All of your data are strings. Should they be? I think numbers would make more sense. This should work in your data are numeric

Comment: Thank you.  In my real data it's a mix of strings and numbers, but, what is consistent is the valueRemaining is a string (strangely enough), as is the oldVoucherId.  The ACTUAL data is '0.00' and I HAVE to encase it in quotes to get it to work on my other attempts.

Comment: Ok, so the fill in your magic value in the `.eq(magic_value)` clause of my solution.

Comment: yes, I tried `.filter(lambda g: g["valueRemaining"].eq("0.00").any())` but it strangely does not group in the results and still has those with '0.00' in the column.  Very strange.

Comment: @robster you might meed to negate the condition. I can never remember if `filter` drops or keeps groups that return True. Again, this could have all been sorted out from the beginning with a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `0` strings:

```
ids = df.loc[df['valueRemaining'].eq('0'), 'oldVoucherId']
```

Alternative is convert to numeric and compare `0` number:

```
ids = df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['valueRemaining'], errors='coerce').eq(0), 'oldVoucherId']
print (ids)
5     2
8     5
10    3
Name: oldVoucherId, dtype: object
```

Then filter all `oldVoucherId` if not exist in `ids` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and inverted mask by `~`:

```
out = df[~df['oldVoucherId'].isin(ids)]
print (out)
   oldVoucherId valuePurchased valueRemaining
0             1             60            NaN
1             1            NaN             50
2             1            NaN             40
11            8             50            NaN
12            9             70            NaN
```

---

For expected ouput remove duplicates with keep last value:

```
out = out.drop_duplicates('oldVoucherId', keep='last')
print (out)
   oldVoucherId valuePurchased valueRemaining
2             1            NaN             40
11            8             50            NaN
12            9             70            NaN
```

Replace missing values in `valueRemaining` by `valuePurchased` and set `NaN`s to `valuePurchased`:

```
out['valueRemaining'] = out['valueRemaining'].fillna(out['valuePurchased'])
out['valuePurchased'] = np.nan
print (out)
   oldVoucherId  valuePurchased valueRemaining
2             1             NaN             40
11            8             NaN             50
12            9             NaN             70
```

Comment: That is beautiful and works perfectly.  I LOVE how this works.  Thank you.   the only thing missing is the purchased value gets lost with the `keep=last`, but that's not end of the world and I can work around that.  Still, it's very nice.  Thank you

Comment: @robster - so only remove `.drop_duplicates('oldVoucherId', keep='last')` , give me a sec.

Comment: Gosh I wish I could buy you a beer / coffee to say thank you.  That's very generous of you.  It's really helped my learning also.

Comment: @robster - You are welcome. I like beer, but I think not easy buy and send gift beer. ;) Nice day.